# Setting view's margin many times in an efficient manner

Tags: android, performance, memory, margin, draw

I am developing an android app which contains a fragment. This fragment looks like youtube's video play fragment. Everything was going well but now I've encountered a problem concerning the memory usage.

I need to change some margin for animation. For doing that, I use a scroll listener to get coordinates between 0 and 1. This is how I set margin of my layout:

```
void setMargin(View view1, int top) {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view1.getLayoutParams();
    params.topMargin = top;
    view1.requestLayout();
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
    if (slideOffset >= 0) {
        int ii = (int) (height * (1 - slideOffset) + (playerViewFirstHeight * slideOffset));
        setMargin(frame_middle, ii);
    } else { }
}
```

My view is that.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_middle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frame_header">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressB_frame_middle_fr_playing"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollV_frame_middle_fr_playing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frame_header">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearL_frame_middle_fr_playing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintL_video_information"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:tint="#757575"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textV_published_at"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_black_24dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:tint="#757575"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_thumb_down_black_24dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageV_whatsapp"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:tint="#757575"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textV_video_category"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textV_video_channel_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textV_video_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textV_video_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="#e0e0e0"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageV_download"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:tint="#757575"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageV_whatsapp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_download_button" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textV_video_channel_name" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerV_related_videos"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

To sum up, I run the above method many times when scrolling. Thus, memory usage increases a lot. Despite destroying this fragment, memory usage stays almost same. It seems to me, my view draws itself many times and doesn't clear previous instances of itself.

I couldn't find any solution for that and I really need your ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, post more of the code concerning your fragment. Just this method is not enough to help.

Comment: I thought it was enough. Because its just about calling the above setmargin method a lot of times one after another in scrooling listener. anyway I am editing the code